# How to save the original file in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, file

I have a problem with saving files in Photoshop.
There are a lot of images where i make the same modification and after I'm done with that i want to save it as fast as possible. For that, I would use Ctrl+S.
However, when I use this shortcut, Photoshop brings up a dialog where i can save it in PSD, but I want to save the changes to the original file, and setting the extension takes up a lot of time.
How could I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain the same layer structure to get rid of this issue. which means for single layered format like .jpg, you have to merge all your layers to the original base layer. You have to keep the same layer structure If you are opening a layered psd or tiff 
You can go for batch option if you are processing large volume with same modifications by creating actions

Answer (score 1):

When you make changes to the image , If you are applying those changes to a new layer , then Photoshop will save the image in it's default file format .psd. Because psd format is capable of containing layer data in it where jpg format can't contain it.

In order to apply the changes to your original image itself , you should either do any of the following.

**1.Apply changes to the same image layer**

While making alterations and adjustments , try to do it on the same image layer itself. If it is simple color correction or minor changes, this method is the easiest.Meanwhile if you need to do some serious manipulations , the following method is recommended.

**2.Flattening the image**

Make changes to the image as you normally do. Once you are finished and satisfied with the result , merge down all the layers into a single layer and save it. Since the image doesn't have any extra layer data , the changes will be applied to the original image itself.

To flatten the image

1. Right click on any of the layers.
2. Select " Flatten image " from the list.
3. Save the image ( Ctrl + S ).

Note : You can flatten the image by the shortcut Ctrl + Shift + E

Answer (score 0):

While you can save the file as a JPG, there is a good reason why it changes the extension when you try to save.  JPG files are lossy and every time you save as a lossy format after making changes, you are going to introduce another generation of loss.  Each generation of loss will further reduce the quality of your overall image, so saving continuously as JPG is not a good idea.

You can use Ctrl-Shift-J as MikeW suggested, but really, you don't want to be overwriting the original file and unless you are finished with all your changes, you really want to be saving in a lossless format.  If you are doing final output after you are done, you really want to be choosing your export settings more carefully so that you get the smallest file size that maintains the quality you need.  In either case, it really isn't as simple as just saving your original JPG.  You would just be saving a completely new file over the old one.